# Perform a custom plugin action when save action is triggered in the eclipse workspace

Tags: java, eclipse, events, plugins, save

I have developed a plugin to generate UUIDs for the files in the work space. I want that action to trigger when save event is called. I am not sure how to implement that?
Any help would be appreciable.

Comment: Save of what? Particular file types or any file type? You can use `IResourceChangeListener` to be told about changes to resources.

Comment: @greg-449 I want to save `.mydsl` file types. But when saving it should perform the even which is triggered by the plugin button

Comment: You can only do things just on save if the particular editor supports that - like the Java editor save actions. Otherwise use `IResourceChangeListener`

Answer (score 0):

You can implement this as ***Save Action***, see Eclipse help:

[JDT Plug-in Developer Guide - **Contributing a clean up and a save action using the clean up extension point**](https://help.eclipse.org/photon/topic/org.eclipse.jdt.doc.isv/guide/jdt_api_contributing_a_cleanup.htm)